# Error when createPresignedDomainUrl is called - AWS SageMaker

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, amazon-sagemaker, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

i'm working with nodeJs and i'm trying to get a presigned Url from SageMaker.
Here's my code:

```
   const sagemaker = new AWS.SageMaker(); 
   module.exports.callSagemaker = async (req, res) => {

   let params = {
      DomainId: '...', 
      UserProfileName: '...', 
      SessionExpirationDurationInSeconds: 120
   };
   await sagemaker.createPresignedDomainUrl(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
      else     console.log(data);           // successful response
   });
}
```

But i got this error:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'Timestamp' of undefined
> at features.constructor.addAuthorization (/home/loredana/Documents/projects/edison_zeus/backend-zeus/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/signers/v2.js:14:24)

My sdk version is:

> "aws-sdk": "^2.800.0"

Is anyone facing the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue updating just for this call, in my AWS configuration, the signature version from 2 to 4.

Now it looks like:

```
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: 'AKID', 
secretAccessKey: 'SECRET', 
region: 'REGION',
signatureVersion:'v4'
});
```